# DAX - Performe a Calculation on a table derived from a calculation

Tags: excel-2013, dax

First, sorry if my title isn't precise in describing my problem. I'll do my best to demonstrate my intention.

I have the following "fact" table in Excel 2013:

```
+----------+-------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| Employee | Month | Branch_Id | Branch Target | Employee sales |
+----------+-------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| John     |     1 | A         |           100 |             20 |
| John     |     2 | A         |           100 |             10 |
| Dave     |     1 | B         |            80 |             30 |
| Dave     |     2 | B         |            80 |              5 |
| Paul     |     1 | A         |           100 |             20 |
| Paul     |     2 | A         |           100 |             60 |
+----------+-------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

I wish to summrize the maximum values of each employee in the following matter:

```
+----------+------------+
| Emoloyee | Max(Sales) |
+----------+------------+
| John     |         20 |
| Dave     |         30 |
| Paul     |         60 |
+----------+------------+
```

I have managed to create the following calculation which partially do the trick:

```
:=Calculate(Max([Employee sales]),all([Month]))
```

this results in the above layout when assinging "Employee" to the PowerPivot rows and the new calculation to the Values area.

Now, I wish to get the SUM of the above table, without being depend on the PowerPivot view. 
In this case, I would like to receive the result "110".

Appreciate your help.

Asaf

Comment: Do you want it as a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: Hi SouravA - as a calculated column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a calculated field as follows:

```
MaxSale :=
CALCULATE ( MAX ( [Employee sales] ), ALL ( facttable[Month] ) )
```

Then you can create another calculated field to sum the max values as follows:

```
SumMaxSales :=
SUMX ( VALUES ( facttable[Employee] ), [MaxSale] )
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!